# Storybook: moduleMetadata doesnt load required services, modules, etc

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, storybook

I tried to load a component of my Angular 8 app into storybook that is hardly integrated in the app structure (animations, store, etc.). But all I get is the error message in Storybook itself that it cant resolve my animation service. I already tried to solve it by import this service in the story's moduleMetadata as provider and also imported it as provider in the component file. But it didnt have any effect.

The error message itself

```
Cannot access 'AnimationService' before initialization ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: ReferenceError: Cannot access 'AnimationService' before initialization
```

Its strange but the assigned files in the following text of the error message are an animation file and service that are not connected to my story's component and the app-store.module.

Here is a **abstracted** snippet of my story configuration
**Code snippets**
The *ParentModule* includes the `@Effect()`s, etc. of an area in the app. This area is a component with many components inside like *ComponentA*.  The mentioned service and animation file are not part of this ParentModule.

```
export default {
  title: 'Name',
  parameters: {
    decorators: [
      withKnobs,
      moduleMetadata({
        declarations: [ComponentA],
        providers: [AnimationService],
        imports: [CommonModule, ParentModule]
      })
    ],
    'in-dsm': {
      id: 'CONTAINER-ID',
      versionFilePath: VERSION FILE,
      componentPath: ComponentA
    }
  }
};
```

**System:**
`Angular Version: 8.2.11`
result of *npx -p @storybook/cli@next sb info*

```
Environment Info:

  System:
    OS: macOS Mojave 10.14.6
    CPU: (12) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz
  Binaries:
    Node: 10.16.1 - /usr/local/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.15.2 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/npm
  Browsers:
    Chrome: 78.0.3904.108
    Firefox: 63.0.3
    Safari: 13.0.3
  npmPackages:
    @storybook/addon-a11y: ^5.2.8 => 5.2.8 
    @storybook/addon-actions: ^5.2.8 => 5.2.8 
    @storybook/addon-backgrounds: ^5.2.8 => 5.2.8 
    @storybook/addon-centered: ^5.2.8 => 5.2.8 
    @storybook/addon-knobs: ^5.2.8 => 5.2.8 
    @storybook/addon-links: ^5.2.8 => 5.2.8 
    @storybook/addon-notes: ^5.2.8 => 5.2.8 
    @storybook/addon-options: ^5.2.8 => 5.2.8 
    @storybook/addons: ^5.2.8 => 5.2.8 
    @storybook/angular: ^5.2.8 => 5.2.8 
    @storybook/core-events: ^5.2.4 => 5.2.4
```

ps. This Angular app was created with the CLI. The Webpack file is not customized and the webpack config inside the storybook folder is empty. Both tsconfigs (in storybook and root folder) contains the `"emitDecoratorMetadata": true`option in the `compilerOptions`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the initialization problem is solved. I simply started the content of the main.js, that starts the AppModule, inside the story. There are some other problems now but its different to this question.

Comment: could you provide some example, please?. I have the same problem with a module instead of a service. Thank you!